# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'userInfo' between objects in different contexts

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm getting **Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'userInfo' between objects in different contexts** while creating relation between two objects. But they have common Persistent coordinator and same context. Please help me to find the issue.

```
- (void)parser:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    // create an ThreadInfo managed object, but don't insert it in our moc yet
    ThreadInfo *info = [[ThreadInfo alloc] initWithEntity:ent insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
    self.threadinfo = info;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

// narrow the fetch to these two properties
NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"userEmail"]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:threadPredicate];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *fetchedItems = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (UserInfo *info in fetchedItems)


{


            if([[attributeDict allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
            {
                if([attributeDict valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
                {
                    self.threadinfo.userEmail=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
                }
            }

            if([[attributeDict allKeys] containsObject:@"thread"])
            {
                if([attributeDict valueForKey:@"thread"]!=[NSNull null])
                {
                    self.threadinfo.threadID=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"thread"];
                }
            }
   if(info!=nil)
    {
        self.threadinfo.userInfo=info;// **CRASH HAPPENED AT THIS LINE**
        [info addThreadDetailsObject:self.threadinfo];
    }


          ThreadInfo *tInfo = nil;

         [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:tInfo];

        if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@", error);
            abort();
        }


}
```

.h

```
@interface batchSave : NSOperation
@property (nonatomic, strong) ThreadInfo *threadinfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UserInfo *userInfos;
```

**CRASH**

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'userInfo' between objects in different contexts source = <ThreadInfo: 0x17dd8280> (entity: ThreadInfo; id: 0x17dda6a0 <x-coredata:///ThreadInfo/t908A5944-FCD9-422B-80D7-83B71D243FB52>
```

Answer (score 0):

ThreadInfo has a `nil` context based on your use of the `-initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` You should be passing in a context here.

Also, you should not be using `-initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.  It is recommended you use the class method `+[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]` and you should not pass `nil` for the context.

### Update

Your code still does not make sense.

You `-init...` the ThreadInfo with a `nil` context for no reason and then call `-insertObject:` later against a `nil` reference called `tInfo`.

If this is your actual code then it has numerous errors and I am having difficulty even tracking what you are trying to do.

As it stands, your created ThreadInfo entity does not have a context.  That is causing the error.

1. Stop using `-initWithEntity: insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` and use the method I recommended.
2. Don't use `-insertObject:`, it is redundant if you pass the context immediately.

   ```
   self.threadinfo.userInfo=info;// **CRASH HAPPENED AT THIS LINE**
   [info addThreadDetailsObject:self.threadinfo];
   ```

Assuming you have a proper bi-directional relationship, these lines are doing the exact same thing and you don't need both.

Why are you storing `threadinfo` as an instance property?  Looks like it should only ever be a local variable.

Change your `-init...` and the crash will be resolved.  But you have other issues in this code.

Comment: I have tried But i'm getting a crash in database save abort() , save error, Code updated

Comment: Also my data not saving to DB while using this fix .

Comment: `if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@", error);
            abort();
        }`

This code comes only after several inserts to the managedobjectcontext in the original code. I was trying to implement batch save. But this error is not allowing me to do batch save.